# XAMARIN C# Android : Permissions : API 23 Methods And Constants Implemented or Not?

Tags: xamarin, permissions, overlay, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-windowmanager

I need use WindowManager with WindowManagerTypes.SystemOverlay argument

This permission enabled on my project

but it's parameter for API < 23

I developed with API 23 (Android 6.0)

I need enable parameter "Draw over other apps" in Settings => Apps => Application Manager Settings of my Android phone of test

I can't find in Xamarin : Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission neither Settings.CanDrawOverlays function, It' IMPLEMENTED OR NOT ?

This element was added from Xamarin.Android Version 5.1.99 (see link below) :

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_5/xamarin.android_5.1.99/level_23_diff/mono.android.dll/

But I can't use elements.

I use a java code to explain problem of implementation (see below), I want do this code but in C# of course.

JAVA CODE

```
public static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE= 5469;

public void testPermission() {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
Result :

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // You have permission
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code seems to work fine for me:

```
private const int RequestCode = 5469;

private void TestPermission()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.M) return;
    if (!Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this)) return;

    var intent = new Intent(Settings.ActionManageOverlayPermission);
    intent.SetPackage(PackageName);
    StartActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == RequestCode)
    {
        if (Settings.CanDrawOverlays(this))
        {
            // we have permission
        }
    }

    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

`Settings` is in the `Android.Provider` namespace

Make sure that in your project properties, set "Compile using Android verision" to an API level equal to or higher than Marshmallow and set "Target Android version" to Marshmallow or higher too.

Also make sure that your Android SDK has those API level installed as well.

Comment: It does not hit OnActivityResult()?